# Does NSString componentsSeparatedByString: return autoreleased array?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, autorelease

In the following method, I'm unsure of why releasing one of the arrays leads to an exception. The only reason that I could see, would be if `componentsSeparatedByString` returns an autoreleased array, but I can't see that the documentation mentions that it do.

```
-(void)addRow:(NSString *)stringWithNumbers;
{

    NSArray *numbers = [stringWithNumbers componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[numbers count]];
    for (NSString *number in numbers) {
        Number *n = [[Number alloc] initWithNumber:number];
        [row addObject:n];
        [n release];
    }
    [rows addObject:row];
    [row release];
//    [numbers release];  <-- leads to exception
}
```

Can anyone confirm if the array is autoreleased? If so, how can I know/why should I have known?
Is it possible to check if any one instance of an object is autoreleased or not by code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, because the name of the method:

- does not start with `new`
- does not start with `alloc`
- is not `retain`
- does not contain `copy`

This is commonly known as the "NARC" rule, and is fully explained here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1

Answer (score -1):

unless you specifically allocate memory, a system method will give you back an autoreleased method.

Comment: -1 false. "malloc" is specifically allocating memory.  `copy` is not guaranteed to return a new object.  `retain` does not allocate new memory.  Yet in all these cases, you own the memory and must relinquish it.

Answer (score -1):

By convention all methods with init or copy in their names return non-autoreleased objects.

Comment: -1 false.  It's the `alloc` method that returns an owned object, not the `init` method.